# Converting double[][] in to float[][]

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a way of converting a double [][] in to a float[][] in Java?
I currently have a for loop in my code that does this and am looking for a better and cleaner way.

Any ideas would be appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: There is no built-in way that I know of. May I ask why you need to convert this array?

Answer (score 3):

There's no quicker way. Also note that not every double value will convert to a float - the range of a float is smaller.